# Connecting wireless system to amplifier

Tags: wireless

First of all I'd like to say that I'm a total newb in this. I've tried googling for some manuals but since the situation is specific I need some help.

To put it shortly, I need to connect wireless microphone (or rather it's reciever box) to the amplifier to get the sound out.

this is the gear:

[Wireless system - LD WSEco16](https://prnt.sc/spda3a)

[Amplifier pic 1 - Yamaha AX-592](https://prnt.sc/spddk9)

[Amplifier pic 2](https://prnt.sc/spdetn)

So I was looking at the [Amplifier sheme](https://prnt.sc/spdi8e) and [Reciever scheme](https://prnt.sc/spdjki) and im not sure which cable to use to connect those two and if it's even possible.

Thanks for help, and kind regards!
Petar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need a 3-pin XLR to RCA cable.

Comment: okay, thank you for a quick reply!

how do I know where to connect RCA into amplifier, looking at the scheme, there obviously isn't any "wireless reciever" port - which on is the right on then ?

Comment: Assuming your wireless receiver outputs at line level, use either of the Line In inputs on the amplifier.